# MAMP Mass Dynamics Virtual Hosts & Mod ReWrites

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, virtual, host

I am running a MAMP stack and have a somewhat default setup.
I have been trying to avoid having to change any rewrites conditions when taking projects out of MAMP, so I had a look at dynamic mass virtual hosts. From what I read, this would allow me to serve projects out of each respective folder in the MAMP web root as a subdomain of localhost. With this each project would have their own document root.

example.localhost would become Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.localhost

I got that all setup by enabling virtual hosts in the httpd.conf and then adding the following to the httpd-vhosts.conf.

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:8888

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin dev@example.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/%0

    RewriteLogLevel 3
    RewriteLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/rewrite.log"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's worth mentioning here that I set the default port in the httpd.conf to 8888 to avoid conflicts.

So this all worked fine but when I reach any part of my project that uses a .htaccess file within a directory and a mod_rewrite is triggered, It performs the rewrite and gives me a 404.

With a simple example of adding a .php to the end of a resource with a .htaccess of:
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

The url of:
  example.localhost/test/api/resource

Should become something like: 
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.localhost/test/api/resource.php

Instead becomes:
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.localhost/example.localhost

This seems to be a problem with the document root being applied by mod_rewrite but I am not sure how to configure this to make sure the document root is correct. I know that when a .htaccess is applied it assumes use of relative paths but i'm not using any leading slashes or anything like that.

There is an importance here for me not to have to change the .htaccess files within the projects as they will need to continue to work on a standard apache setup.

I am no expert at these configurations and I am largely self taught when it comes to apache so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at MAMP Pro, which has a GUI for multiple local hosts? It's the best way to use it...

Comment: I am trying to create these multiple hosts dynamically so I don't need to create and maintain new virtual hosts for every project. Would MAMP Pro still offer a better way to this?

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think you can set them up to be created on the fly. It might be a security issue if you could be able to...

Comment: Ah yeah, probably. This is only used on a development machine though

Comment: If it were me, I'd look at MAMP Pro, and just create each of your hosts manually. You literally need to enter a name, and the directory where your files are.. and that's it. It's pretty simple. Oh, and you'll need to enter the hosts in your hosts file of course.